# Hiding and showing div's from menu

Tags: javascript, html, menu, hide, show

I'm quite novice with javascript and can't get a working version of a page that would show/hide divs based on the selected menu item. I always end to have only menu items visible.
How to access and cotnrol to content portion of the html from the menu.

Hiding is probabbly quite easy, something like:

```
$("#div1").hide();
$("#div2").hide();
```

But I have not found a way to show a div related to menu selection and hiding rest.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd" >
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      // menu css 
      .hor_menu{display: inline-block;}
      .hor_menu{ height: 25; font-size: 18px;}
      .hor_menu li{list-style: none; float: left; margin-right: 4px; padding: 5px;}
      .hor_menu li.active {
        background-color: #e9e9e9;
      }
      .hor_menu li:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    //top menu
    <ul class="hor_menu" id="menu">
      <li a class="active" id="item1"><a>Menu item 1</a></li>
      <li id="item2">Menu item 2</li>
      <li id="item3">Menu item 3</li>
    </ul>
    // content divs
    <div id="div1">
      <p>Show me when menu item 1 selected</p>
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
      <p>Show me when menu item 2 selected</p>
    </div>
    <div id="div3">
      <p>Show me when menu item 3 selected</p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var make_menuitem_active = function()
      {
        //Get menu siblings
        var siblings =($(this).siblings());

        //Deactivate selection
        siblings.each(function (index)
          {
            $(this).removeClass('active');    
          }
        )
        //Add the clicked button class
        $(this).addClass('active');
      }
      //Attach events to menu
      $(document).ready(
        function()
        {
          $(".hor_menu li").click(make_menuitem_active);
        }
      )
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using jQuery's hide/show:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  make_menuitem_active();
})

function make_menuitem_active() {
  $("#div1").show();
  $("#div2").hide();
  $("#div3").hide();
  $("#item1").on("click", function() {
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
    $("#div1").show();
    $("#div1").siblings("div").hide();
  })
  $("#item2").on("click", function() {
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
    $("#div2").show();
    $("#div2").siblings("div").hide();
  })
  $("#item3").on("click", function() {
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
    $("#div3").show();
    $("#div3").siblings("div").hide();
  })
}
```

```css
.hor_menu {
  display: inline-block;
}

.hor_menu {
  height: 25;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.hor_menu li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.hor_menu li.active {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.hor_menu li:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="hor_menu" id="menu">
  <li class="active" id="item1"><a>Menu item 1</a></li>
  <li id="item2">Menu item 2</li>
  <li id="item3">Menu item 3</li>
</ul>
<div id="div1">
  <p>Show me when menu item 1 selected</p>
</div>
<div id="div2" class="hide">
  <p>Show me when menu item 2 selected</p>
</div>
<div id="div3" class="hide">
  <p>Show me when menu item 3 selected</p>
</div>
```